# What's the optimal tool to fire scheduled events with datetime from DB?

Tags: python, database, scheduled-tasks, airflow, message-queue

There's a list of events in DB (MongoDB now, but could switch to any other solution). Each even has a specific datetime with timezone when it needs to be fired. By "fired" I mean custom API call, signal, anything similar.

Currently, I keep the DB table sorted by datetime and check the first entries every second to check if it's ready to fire. It works, stable enough, but doesn't feel like an optimal one.

Another solution could be using AirFlow and generating DAGs, but it's more regularly-focused (like every Wednesday at 3:00 AM), so even while it's possible to fire predefined events with enabling limits, it feels "hacky". Message queues like RabbitMQ or Kafka possibly won't fit also, because the idea is to fire the event at the specific datetime (maybe even to add it to some queue), not just to process it when it's fired.

So, is there any task-specific tool or DB solution to work with such a task? Or the current solution of checking first entries is good enough?

Comment: Look at temporal.io

Comment: @MaximFateev the solution is brilliant (like, really), but need to wait for its Python implementation :) For now, will stick with Mongo capped collections and cron :)